# Tcp client and server at same time

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

I’ve to implement a client communication interface with a server that’s a bit weird and I’ve doubts about how to develop it.

Communication follows this rules:

1. It’s done vía TCP only.
2. Client sends to server an XML identifying itself.
3. If server response is OK, client starts listen incomming requests from server.

Can a TcpClient act as a server? 
What would be the best way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "If server response is OK, client starts listen incomming requests from server." do you mean the server expects the client to open a port it can connect to, or that it sends requests down the same connection the client initiated?

Comment: @DaisyShipton It sends requests down the same connection the client initiated. In fact, server act as a proxy. Some other client make requests to server, server redirects to my client, my client responds to server and server sends response to client who made the request.

Comment: Just don't fall into a common beginner mistake with TCP. TCP is an endless stream of bytes in both directions. It doesn't do *messages*, in that you don't get 1-1 match of calls of `Send`/`Write` at one end being matched with calls to `Receive`/`Read` at the other end. If you want *messages* (or requests/responses, or whatever you want to call them), it's up to *you* to implement messaging atop the endless stream of bytes (or move to a higher level protocol that implements these for you)

Answer (score 1):

Once the connection has been established, there's no significant distinction between "client" and "server". There's just a TCP stream that can be used to communicate information in both directions. You should be fine to use `TcpClient`, because it sounds like you don't need to be listening for new connections or anything like that; you just need to read requests from the existing stream and provide responses.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks. The problem is how to deal with multiple requests since it’s not a true server. This is my main headache

Comment: @Merrin: We'd need to know a lot more detail in order to help with that. I suggest you ask a new question with details about what the protocol looks like for the requests and responses, what you've tried already and what's gone wrong.

Comment: Ok, I’ll do that. Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

After establishing connection to server, client can send or receive any data. So if you just want to listen requests from server:

```
while(client.Connected)
{
   client.Client.Receive(data);
   DoSomething(data);
}
```